# Debug Pound Varnish Apache

Tags: ajax, apache, varnish, pound

I have a server configured with Apache and Varnish, we are using Pound to handle port 443.

Everything runs smoothly and the site speed is amazing.

I have one little bug, when clicking on an AJAX button, sometimes the request hangs for 60 seconds before posting.

I am trying to figure out where the bottleneck is and what's holding things up.

What "listener" or "debugger" can I use to trace exactly what happens on the server when I click on that AJAX button on the front end.

Beginner question, so if I'm missing the obvious please let me know